# Function recursion with jQuery - IE compatibility

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, recursion

I'm creating a JSon jQuery caller to read the accomplishment percentage of a task.

I just call getProcess.php that returns percent like this : `{"error":0,"percent":21.1}`

Here is my jQuery code :

```
$(function(){
    runGetPercent(01); // 01 is an id I need in my PHP script
});

function runGetPercent(id){

    $.getJSON("getProcess.php", // PHP script I call
    {"id": id}, // id parameter
    function(data){
        if (data.error == 0)
        {
            $("#percent").html(data.percent); // updating percentage
        }
        else {
            $("#percent").html("Error!"); // report error
        }

        if (data.percent < 100) {
            runGetPercent(id); // loop until process is running
        }
    });
}
```

That works like a charm on Firefox 16.

I need that code working on IE8 too for compatibility with many of users but the browser froze...

Is there something I missed ?

I tried to work it with setTimeout and things like that without any chance.

Thanks for your answers !

Comment: Have you tried runGetPercent("01"); ?

Comment: Have you tried to set a breakpoint on your anonymous function and walk through it?

Comment: @roasted : yes, same problem with IE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chances are IE is caching the remote request and just firing the same callback immediately, every time. Try adding a unique querystring parameter to your request and see if that works.

```
$.getJSON("getProcess.php", { "id": id, "_nocache", new Date().getTime() }, function(data) {
  // Process data
});
```